# Set option selected with rails symbol

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-select

I've this select in my form:

```
<%= select_tag :x, options_from_collection_for_select(@dmj, :id, :name, :selected), {class: "form-control"} %>
```

but when I load the page, the option whose value is set in db is not selected.

The symbol `:selected` comes from a SQL query in the controller and if I try to replace the `:name` with `:selected` in the `options_from_collection_for_select`, I can see that its value is correct.

Also, if I manually set the integer in the `options_from_collection_for_select` the corresponding option is selected.

Why do I not succeed in selecting the option with the symbol?

EDIT:

My query is making a join to retrieve the selected from a Join table. Here's the query:
@dmj = DiscoveryModeInjury.find_by_sql("SELECT D.name, D.id,   L.discovery_mode_injury_id AS selected
FROM
discovery_mode_injuries D
 LEFT OUTER JOIN
link_dismodeinj_hospitalizations L
ON
D.id = L.discovery_mode_injury_id
 WHERE
flag = 'disc'
 ORDER BY
D.name")

If I have understood correctly Akash Srivastava's suggestion, the query should return the DiscoveryModeInjury id field? How..? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your query for `:selected` returns an `:id` field. Basically, the `selected` option in `options_from_collection_for_select()` should be of the same field as the `value` field of the same, which is `:id` in your case. Many of us make this mistake of keeping the result of `selected` as an object of the `collection`.